# IF/AND/OR/THEN in Excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I'm stuck trying to crack an IF/THEN where a specific character is not in one column, and another does have a certain set of text. I'm starting to wonder if it can be done.

I've tried several juggled around versions of `=If(AND(...`, I've tried `=IF(NOT(OR...`, I've even tried breaking it apart with `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH...` which really isn't right.

I'm looking for situations where `AE2` does not contain `"*/*"`, and `B2` contains `"*IND*"`.

The basic formula I keep coming back to is `=IF(AND(AE2<>"*/*", B2="*IND*"), "DAF","")` but this is showing all of the columns as `DAF` then, which isn't right. I feel like I'm close, but I'm missing some little critical thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(AE2,"*/*")=0,COUNTIF(B2,"*IND*")=1),"DAF","")
```

Comment: That did it! I stayed away from COUNTIF because I narrowly thought of it only giving me a 1 or a 0. Thank you!